# How long more must I wait?

Tags: grammaticality, difference, sentence-request

Will it be grammatically correct to say **"How long more must I wait?"** instead of **"How much longer must I wait?"**. Do they convey the same meaning and stress?

I just wish to avoid the most common phrase.

Are there any more examples?

Comment: **How long more** is ungrammatical. **more** means "an additional quantity [of something]".  It cannot be modified by adjective "long", since quantities don't have physical dimension/extension in space. You could ask "How *many* more must I wait?" if you had been talking about hours or minutes or days or weeks or months or years or decades or centuries or eons or semesters or quarters or ... in a previous sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How long more" is not grammatical English.  You can say, "How many more," if you specify a *countable* unit of time, or, "How much more," if talking about (uncountable) time in general.  For example:

> How many more days must I wait before they let me know if I've been accepted?
>
> After fertilizing, how much more time must I wait before planting new seedlings?

However, these expressions are not as common or natural as, "How much longer must I ..."  They are common in other contexts:

> How many more days until graduation?
>
> Traveling for work, how much time do you get to spend with your family?